# Django : How to handle css/js specific to a template tag?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

**Background:**

I have a `css` and a `js` that is used only by the Google maps template tag, that I include in my templates where-ever needed.

```
Inside template tag google_map:
...
...
return render_to_string('google_map.html', context)
```

Inside `google_map.html` I have the required `css` and the `js` :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
```

**My problem is :**

*I have a page with 3 maps, therefore 3 calls to the template tag. This implies the css and the js is included 3 times in the same page. [Should not happen]*

*Now, I can-not include these css and js in the header of the page, since all the pages are not having the maps so there, on all those pages it would be a burden.*

What should I do, so that if a page has 3 or more maps, even then there is only a single include of the css & js and not repeated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend following the pattern introduced by Paul Irish for [Markup-based unobtrusive comprehensive DOM-ready execution](http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/). There's a number of side benefits to the approach such as encapsulation, namespacing, etc., but the chief benefit for you would be conditional execution of JavaScript based on a id or class on `<body>`.

So in your base template change your `<body>` tag to something like the following:

```
<body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
```

Then, for templates that need maps just do:

```
{% block body_class %}{% if block.super %}{{ block.super }} {% endif %}maps{% endblock %}
```

That looks a little complicated, but all it's doing is inheriting from the values any parent templates set for that block. The `if` block is used to conditionally include the space needed between multiple classes.

Finally, in your JavaScript you simply create a module for "maps" as the article describes and put all your map-specific JS there.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a new django block in the `<head>` section of your base template you extend:

```
<head>
  /* ... other css/js calls */
  {% block googlemapassets %}{% endblock %}
</head>
```

Then in the view template (assuming `content` is you main content block):

```
{% block content %}
  {% google_map %}
{% endblock %}
{% block googlemapassets %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Obvious, but I am looking for something better.